# python put into list

Tags: python, math, factors

```
def problem(n):
    myList = []
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            myList.append(i)

    return myList
```

with this code I was wondering how you would get the factors for example 12 to print out as[[6,2],[3,4]] something like this dosnt have to be in same order thanks.

Comment: update post as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import math

def problem(n):
    myList = []
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            myList.append([i, int(n/i)])

    return myList
```

To get the factor pair, this divides `n` by `i`, if `i` is a factor, which will by `i`'s pair.

example:

```
print(problem(12)) #output: [[2, 6], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: @joey `int(n/i)` divides `n` by`i` and turns the answer into an int.

Comment: what about the not in my list part what does that do, also not to be a pain is there another way to do that. also could u do it without a library

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct . Using range you are not taking the number. Just add n+1 instead of n. That should work. Also you are not stroing the divident in the list. I added that too.

```
def problem(n):
    myList = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if n % i == 0 and [int(n/i),i] not in myList:
            myList.append([i,int(n/i)])

    return myList
```

Comment: what does ([i,int(n/i)]) do

Comment: This results in duplicate factors

Comment: but thorughly what the I and the (n/i) do

Comment: i is running number and n is the divident (n=6 , i=2 , divident=6/2=3)

Comment: @gommb: Correct . Edited my post

Comment: Sorry didnt get. If you don't have factors you want to return False ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way. Loop using `range` and check if `is_integer`

```
num = 12
set([tuple(sorted(j)) for j in [[i, int(num/i)] for i in range(2,num) if (num/i).is_integer()]]
)
#Output:
#{(2, 6), (3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the division only once:

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
    d, m = divmod(n, i)
    if m == 0:
        myList.append([i, d])
```

You will not get duplicates with upper limit `sqrt(n)`